# How access action helper in view script?

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, helper

How access action helper in view script?

```
$this->view->helper = $this->_helper->SomeHelper;
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't ... or at least you can't do that "normally". You can do

```
$this->view->whatever = $this->_helper->flashMessager;
```

But it's not the right way... I guess. You can do it also using static call, which is little better.

```
$flashMessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('flashMessenger');
```

Comment: Ohh The Mighty manual, I need to get used to read documentation first

Answer (score -2):

In your Bootstrap.php make sure to register the view helper directory

```
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH .'/views/helpers', 'View_Helper');
$view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/','ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');
```

then in your view just call

```
echo $this->someHelper();
```

Comment: I mean action helpers like FlashMessanger. I just wanna get it in my layout.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect this then please.

Comment: He asks that in his question :)